# Although I put the alphabet path, I still get an error that alphabet should exist and be readable

Tags: python, path, mozilla-deepspeech

I followed this link in order to create a model another language than english
https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/tutorial-how-i-trained-a-specific-french-model-to-control-my-robot/22830
I followed the steps but the problem is that I get the following error:

```
FATAL Flags parsing error: flag --alphabet_config_path=/home/DeepSpeech/data/vlad/alphabet.txt: The file pointed to by --alphabet_config_path must exist and be readable.
```

My sh file is the following:

```
 #!/bin/sh
set -xe
if [ ! -f DeepSpeech.py ]; then
    echo "Please make sure you run this from DeepSpeech's top level directory."
    exit 1
fi;

python -u DeepSpeech.py \
  --train_files data/vlad/train/train.csv \
  --test_files data/vlad/test/test.csv \
  --train_batch_size 64 \
  --test_batch_size 1 \
  --n_hidden 250 \
  --epochs 100 \
  --checkpoint_dir data/vlad/fine_tuning/\
  --export_dir /home/DeepSpeech/data/vlad/results/model_export/ \
  --checkpoint_dir /home/DeepSpeech/data/vlad/fine_tuning/ \
  --alphabet_config_path /home/DeepSpeech/data/vlad/alphabet.txt \
  --lm_binary_path /home/DeepSpeech/data/vlad/lm.binary \
  --lm_trie_path /home/DeepSpeech/data/vlad/trie\
  "$@"
```

Do you have any ideas what can I do?

Comment: on the shell if you type "cat /home/DeepSpeech/data/vlad/alphabet.txt" does it print it out?

Comment: try putting an absolute path here: -train_files data/vlad/train/train.csv

Comment: I did manage to solve the problem, but now i get some tensorflow warning. I used the requirements for deepspeech 0.6.1.

Comment: Generally, use current 0.9.3 branch. For more, head over to their Discourse and search: https://discourse.mozilla.org/c/deepspeech/247

Comment: How did you solve this issue? Could you please update the post with your solution?